# Como ir para o próximo campo( um EditText) sem ter que apertar Next no android?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um palavras cruzadas  e cada campo  é um EditText  como no exemplo a baixo :

```
// GRIDLAYOUT USADO PARA ORGANIZAR OS EDIT TEXT EM UMA MATRIZ
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="382dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.26">

     <EditText
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/letra1_1"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_semborda"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/letra1_2"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_semborda"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        />
```

gostaria de pular para o próximo campo automaticamente  quando o usuário colocar um caracter no campo em que ele esta.

tentei usar o atributo `android:nextFocus` mas ele pede o enter para pular pra outro campo.

Segue abaixo o código java como ficou ... mas o app para de funcionar quando eu acesso a tela dessa activity

```
package com.example.android.cruzadinhas_eic;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LeptospiroseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText letra1_1;
public EditText letra1_2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leptospirose);





    letra1_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            letra1_2.requestFocus();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
    });

    }
}
```

agradeço pela ajuda de vocês ! abraços

Comment: Você tem de inicializar os atributos `letra1_1` e `letra1_2`, no `onCreate()`, recorrendo ao método `findViewById()`

Comment: Muito obrigado ! agora funcionouu ! abraçoss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso, coloquei no after por ser a ação dispara apos soltar o click, mas você pode fazer em outros metodos ou colocar uns teste para determinada letra.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           otherEditText.requestFocus();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Comment: Como isso faz o *input* passar para o próximo *EditText*?

Comment: coloca o letra2.requestFocus(); dentro do evento afterTextChanged(). acho que seria se eu entendi bem o que precisa.

Comment: Sim é isso, mas você não colocou na resposta.

Comment: Foi mal, eu me esqueci do método requestFocus()

Comment: Obrigadoo ! não tinha  a minima ideia de como fazer isso rsrs,  mas coloquei esse trecho e o  app parou de funcionar na hora que coloquei ele para rodar ...   posso fazer um update da pergunta com o código java  para vocês verem se eu estou fazendo algo errado?sou novo aqui desculpa qquer coisa ...

Comment: @LinkonLouvison Sim, coloca o código e o *log* de erro

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que o usuário esteja editando o campo letra1 e você queira, após a edição, posicionar o cursor na letra2, você pode faze-lo assim:

```
letra2.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Isso só resolve parte do problema, falta explicar como executar isso automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

tenta :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public EditText edLetterOne,edLetterTwo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edLetterOne = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edLetterTwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        edLetterOne.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////
    //////////// TextWatcher ////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2){}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if(count > 0) edLetterTwo.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable){}
    };
}
```

e no seu layout.xml file onde voce tem o seu EditText use o attribute

```
 android:maxLength="1"
```

Comment: descupa pela ultima linha ai , nao tiinha visto ela no seu layout.xml file